# Image does not appear in JPanel using BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

I have a GUI with a created JPanel and a "Start" button. All I need is when I click "Start", an image will be loaded and appear on that JPanel.
But my problem is when I click "Start", nothing happens.
Can anyone help me fix this problem?
Here is my code:

```
private BufferedImage image;
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    public ImagePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\HienTran\\Desktop\\Miranda-Kerr-16-240x320.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception...
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

private void startBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
    startBtn.setEnabled(false);
    imageArea.add(new ImagePanel());    // imageArea is the JPanel in the GUI
}
```

When I replace 2 lines of imageArea by creating a new JFrame as below, that JFrame shows up with the image I added.

```
private void startBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
    startBtn.setEnabled(false);
    JFrame test = new JFrame("Window"); 
    test.add(new ImagePanel()); 
    test.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() + 30); 
    test.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However, that probably won't help because by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout and a FlowLayout respects the size of the component. Your ImagePanel will have a size of (0, 0) since you did not override the `getPreferredSize()` method.

There is no need to create a custom panel to paint your image. Just use a `JLabel` with an `Icon` then you let the label worry about the size.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics. Maybe the section on `How to Use Labels` would be a good place to start. The tutorial will also show you a better way to design your class wo that you follow Swing guidelines.

Comment: Sorry for creating the new question :(
I tried the JLabel as you said and it still cannot solve my problem. The image still doesn't show up in the JPanel

Comment: @user2716653 Saying it doesn't work does not give us any information. You need to post a `SSCCE`.

Comment: @user2716653 : The problem can be that the image is not found, if this is the case, try to write `ex.printStackTrace()` inside the catch block, and see the stack trace, if any, that might can give more details :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw, The other answer already suggested this. Also the OP has stated that the image display when directly added to the frame. Again the OP needs to learn how to ask a proper question which means posting a SSCCE so we don't keep guessing.

Comment: @camickr : Too true, I am restraining myself too, from further guess work, though upvoted the other answer too, for emphasising the need for Stack Trace :-)

Answer (score 2):

First fix a bit:

```
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\HienTran\\Desktop\\Miranda-Kerr-16-240x320.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStacktrace(); // see if there is an exception, like not finding or something
    }
```

than:
If you add a panel, than need a layout refresh and a gui refresh:

```
imageArea.add(new ImagePanel()); 
imageArea.revalidate(); // refresh layout
imageArea.repaint(); // shedule painting
```

Comment: Weird, I tried. Nothing appears in catch exception so I supposed there isn't any exceptions. Added the revalidate() and repaint() and yet it still doesn't work... :(

Comment: @user2716653 than you are adding the new component where is not visible die to layout. Set a new BorderLayout() and add it to Center Constaints, maybe you have a NullLayout or so